# MTB tire compatibility

Tags: tire, compatibility

My mountain bike has on a pair of 26"×2.10 tires. I want to go for a wider set of tires,Can i replace them with a pair of 26"×2.5?

Comment: Welcome to the site - this is a common question and has been asked before.  The linked duplicate post already mentions all the possible pitfalls and what to measure, so your question will be closed as a duplicate.  Please don't take it personally, and good luck with your changes.

Comment: Likely frame clearance will be a problem.